# Complex equation - problem

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

So i have this equation:

$$z^2 -iz=\left|z-i\right|,\quad z\in\mathbb{C}.$$

So i just used: $z=a+bi$ and got to this:

$$a^2+(2ab-a)i=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}.$$

Now i have a problem: there is no $i$ on the right side. 
So is it okay to assume that $2ab-a=0$ or not?

Comment: Are you sure that type the question correct ?

Comment: What do you mean? Yeah i did type it correctly.

Comment: you should have a $b^2$ at the very least so check the equation.

Comment: Well on the left side i got: $a^2+2abi-b^2-ai+b^2$ so it isn't there anymore.

Comment: .$z^2-iz=(a+bi)^2-i(a+bi)=a^2+2abi-b^2-ia+b=a^2-b^2+b+(2ab-a)i$.

Comment: Oh i see,my mistake.

Comment: @user246608, you may assume that the imaginary part is 0 and your reasoning is fine.

Comment: $z(z-i)=|z-i|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $z=i$ or ($|z|=1$ and $\text{arg}\,z=-\text{arg}\,(z-i)$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $z=i$ or ($|z|=1$ and $\bar z=z-i$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $z=i$ or $z=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac12 i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^2 -iz=\left|z-i\right|$$
$$(a+bi)^2-i(a+bi)=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}\\a^2-b^2+2abi-ia+b=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}\\(a^2-b^2+b)+i(2ab-a)=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}\\ \to \left\{\begin{matrix}
a(2b-1)=0 & \to  & \\ a=0 ,or,b=\frac {1}{2}
a^2-b^2+b=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2} &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
now check for $a=0$ ,$b=\frac{1}{2}$
$$a=0 \to a^2-b^2+b=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2} \to b-b^2=\sqrt{0+(b-1)^2} \to \\ b(1-b)=|b-1| \to b=\pm1 $$
$$b=\frac{1}{2} \to a^2-b^2+b=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2} \\a^2-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{a^2+(\frac{-1}{2})^2} \to \\\left(a^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2=\left[\sqrt{a^2+\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^2}\right]^2\\a^4+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{1}{2}a^2=a^2+\frac{1}{4}\\a^4-\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{3}{16}=0 \to a=\pm1.27$$

Comment: It cannot be that $|a|>1$ since $|z|=1$. Even $a=0$ and $b=-1$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can take another approach, too.. Take a modulus in both side. If $z\neq i$, so $z=e^{i\theta}$. Since $im(z^2-iz)=0$ we have $\sin(2\theta)=\cos \theta$ and we obtain the solutions.